# Filter a ListBox that's filled with MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, mariadb, recordset

I see a lot of people that filter their Userform's ListBox using a TextBox or a ComboBox.

I'd like it to do mine, but unlike them, my Listbox is filled using a MySQL Recordset, while they are using an Excel Spreadsheet

There is my actual code, where SelectProduct is my Userform and ListRef is my Listbox.

```vb
  Requete = "SELECT Reference,Nom,Marque,PrixVente FROM Produits_Beta"
            rs.Open Requete, oConnect


SelectProduct.ListeRef.Clear
SelectProduct.ListeRef.Column = rs.GetRows
```

The Listbox is soon going to show 700+ results and I need a way for my user to filter them to find what they need.

If I used a Spreadsheet to get the Listbox value, my Filter code owuld look like this.
(Code originally from Ralph)

```vb
Dim i As Long
Dim arrList As Variant

Me.ListeRef.Clear
If TheoricalSheet.Range("A" & TheoricalSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TXBoxFilter.Value) <> vbNullString Then
    arrList = TheoricalSheet.Range("A1:A" & TheoricalSheet.Range("A" & TheoricalSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For i = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
        If InStr(1, arrList(i, 1), Trim(Me.TXBoxFilter.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
            Me.ListeRef.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End If
If Me.ListeRef.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListeRef.Selected(0) = True
```

I could, but I would need a way to paste all a MySQL table to an hidden Spreadsheet, and, again, I have no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way to filter SQL data for display is to use a `WHERE` clause in your query.  That will work when you have seven, seven hundred, or seven million rows.

You might try something like this:

```
 SELECT Reference,Nom,Marque,PrixVente 
   FROM Produits_Beta 
  WHERE Produit LIKE CONCAT('filter value', '%')
  ORDER BY Produit
  LIMIT 100
```

If you give an empty string for `filter value` you'll get the first hundred rows; your user will quickly see that a filter is necessary.

With no filter value, you get `WHERE Produit LIKE '%'` to not filter. With `Pom` as the filter value you'll get `WHERE Produit LIKE 'Pom%'` That matches `Pomme`, `Pomme de terre`, and `Pomade`, for example.

**Edit** You can use `%pom%` in LIKE. Here's the thing, however: if your search term has `%` coming first, the DBMS cannot use index lookups to find your data, so the searches will be slower. With a thousand rows to search, this doesn't matter. With millions of rows, it matters a lot.

Many developers of this kind of software use queries a lot to filter their data. DBMSs are built for it. The whole point of a DBMS is to allow software to handle vast sets of data efficiently.

**Pro tip**: Always use `ORDER BY` in your queries. If you don't the database server is free to present results in any order it finds most efficient at the moment. That's called *unstable sorting* and it drives users crazy.

Comment: Yeah but that would mean I would have to do a query everytime. That might what I'll go after thought. Tell me, could I make it so when TXBoxFilter with Pom, the request will be `%pom%` and it would get `Pomme` as well as `Grosse Pomme`

Answer (score 0):

The Worksheet.Visible attribute has three options, as follows:

```
xlSheetVisible 'The usual visible worksheet.
xlSheetHidden 'Worksheet that is hidden but may be turned visible by the user.
xlSheetVeryHidden 'Worksheet that is hidden but may only be turned visible via VBA.
```

If you were to create a hidden sheet to receive this data, you could try it as such:
Let's say you have first created a Worksheet in  your workbook, (vba)named ws. In order to fetch the data from this recordset, you'll have to loop through its records and copy the value of each to a row:

```
'Header
With ws
    .Cells(1,1) = "Reference"
    .Cells(1,2) = "Nom"
    .Cells(1,3) = "Marque"
    .Cells(1,4) = "PrixVente"
End With

'Rows
Dim i as Long: i = 2

with Requete
    If not (.EOF and .BOF) then
        .movefirst

        Do until .EOF                
            ws.Cells(i,1) = .Fields("Reference")
            ws.Cells(i,2) = .Fields("Nom")
            ws.Cells(i,3) = .Fields("Marque")
            ws.cells(i,4) = .Fields("PrixVente")

            .MoveNext
            i=i+1
        Loop
    End If
End With
```

Then, if you don't want the user to have access to your sheet, just do:

```
ws.visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

If you plan to refresh the query and fetch the data again, you'll have to clear your worksheet beforehand.
Also, it might be good to order your data in your SQL query, so that the listbox gets populated alphabetically, should it suit your needs.

Comment: That's a very fast way to get my info and I might go for it for it would be pretty fast

Comment: Okay! Best of luck. Please do come back once you're done to accept the answer and close the question, if it's solved.